# Scanning all/specific arrays values when filtering an array of arrays

Tags: swift

Here is the sample code:

```
var myArray = [["one", "two"], ["three", "four"]]

var filteredArray = myArray.filter{ value in value[1] != "four"}

filteredArray //[["one", "two"]]
```

This code is supposed to filter out any array that contains "four". It does it properly, but only because I target specific array with value[1] because I know it contains "four".
How should I reformat this code so I don't need to specify specific array, so it will scan all values in there? When using a "for loop", we have a declared "i" variable we can use. But how to do similar with .filter function ?

Also, even more specific, how could I reformat this code so I can filter array and exclude all that have "four" but specifically as their second value (index [1]) and not if they have "four" in any other index position as in previous requirement. Again in the absence of an "i" variable, I don't see how to do it. Your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Knowing that the filter callback receives an inner array at each iteration, we can use `reduce` on that array to check if it contains the `four` string:

```
var filteredArray = myArray.filter {
    let count = $0.reduce(0) {
        $0 + ($1 == "four" ? 1 : 0)
    }

    return count == 0
}
```

In the `reduce` closure, if one or more elements is `four`, the return value will be an integer greater than zero.

Comment: smart it helped me get it tsk